# How I can know if the function passing by value /reference?

Tags: c++

These two functions add and subtract two integers I need in this code how i can know that this function passing by value or not and what is the difference between printing the value in the body of function and the void main.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
void sumAndDifference(int n1, int n2, int sum, int diff) {
    sum = n1 + n2;
    diff = n1 - n2;
}
void main() {
    int sum = 0, diff = 0, x = 200, y = 88;
    sumAndDifference(x, y, sum, diff); //calling the function
    cout << "\n Sum is " << sum << "\n Diff is " << diff;
}
return 0;
```

And

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
void sumAndDifference(int n1, int n2, int sum, int diff) {
    sum = n1 + n2;
    diff = n1 - n2;
    cout << "\n Sum is " << sum;    //print sum in the function
    cout << "\n Diff is " << diff;   // print diff in the function
}
void main() {
    int sum = 0, diff = 0, x = 200, y = 88;
    sumAndDifference(x, y, sum, diff);   //calling the function
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Arguments are always passed by value unless otherwise specified with a `&`. I believe you may be confused about how scopes work in c++.

Comment: In c++, `main` must always have the return type `int`. And your `return 0;` are sitting alone outside of a function scope. I assume they were meant to be at the end of `main`.

Comment: Suspect troll..

Comment: @MartinJames Or victim of some terrible C++ teaching.

Answer (score 0):

They're passing by value. You can just look at the signature, e.g. `foo(int x)` by value and `foo(int& x)` by reference. So in your example, to modify the *out* parameters you'd use the signature

```
void sumAndDifference(int n1, int n2, int& sum, int& diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I fixed up your code.

```
  #include <iostream> 

    using namespace std;
    void sumAndDifference (int n1, int n2, int sum, int diff) 
    { 
        sum = n1 + n2;
        diff = n1 - n2;
    }
    void main () 
    {
        int sum = 0, diff = 0, x = 200, y = 88;
        sumAndDifference (x,y,sum, diff); //calling the function
        cout << "\n Sum is " << sum << "\n Diff is " << diff;   
    }
   //&&
    #include <iostream> 

    using namespace std;
    void sumAndDifference (int n1, int n2,int sum, int diff)
    {
        sum = n1 + n2;
        diff = n1 - n2;
        cout << "\n Sum is " << sum;    //print sum in the function
        cout << "\n Diff is " << diff;   // print diff in the function
    }

    void main ()
    {
        int sum = 0, diff = 0, x = 200, y = 88;
        sumAndDifference (x,y, sum, diff);   //calling the function
    }
```

Second of all, both functions presented here pass their arguments by value.
Example of a function that passes arguments by reference could be

```
void SumAndDifference(int n1, int n2, int &sum, int &diff)
```

Comment: Pointers and references are different.  You can pass by reference (your example) or you can pass by pointer: `int * sum, int * diff`.  One big difference is that a variable passed by reference refers to an existing variable (from the caller).  A pointer can point to anywhere in memory and may not point to a valid object.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews this is correct. Pointers can more than often lead to nothing.

Comment: Your text and example don't correlate, "pass a function by reference you need to use pointers".  In your example, you are using references not pointers.